# Android app keeps force closing when setting ListView Adapter

Tags: java, android

My I am trying to get the hang of android development, but I've hit a snag. I have a ListView and I wan't to populate it with some random items. But when I try to set the adapter of the listview the application force closes.

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <ListView
       android:id="@+id/accountList"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

   </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.testapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    static final String[] TEXTS = new String[] {"test1","test2"};

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ListView lv = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.accountList);
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.id.accountList, TEXTS));            
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

logcat:

```
05-20 13:44:28.154: E/AndroidRuntime(585): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-20 13:44:28.154: E/AndroidRuntime(585): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060000 type #0x12 is not valid
05-20 13:44:28.154: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2110)
05-20 13:44:28.154: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:857)
05-20 13:44:28.154: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
05-20 13:44:28.154: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:371)
05-20 13:44:28.154: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
05-20 13:44:28.154: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2033)
05-20 13:44:28.154: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1244)
05-20 13:44:28.154: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1155)
05-20 13:44:28.154: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
05-20 13:44:28.154: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
05-20 13:44:28.154: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1369)
05-20 13:44:28.154: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:660)
05-20 13:44:28.154: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
05-20 13:44:28.154: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
05-20 13:44:28.154: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
05-20 13:44:28.154: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
05-20 13:44:28.154: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
05-20 13:44:28.154: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:812)
05-20 13:44:28.154: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
05-20 13:44:28.154: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
05-20 13:44:28.154: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
05-20 13:44:28.154: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
05-20 13:44:28.154: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2092)
05-20 13:44:28.154: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
05-20 13:44:28.154: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1064)
05-20 13:44:28.154: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
05-20 13:44:28.154: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-20 13:44:28.154: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-20 13:44:28.154: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-20 13:44:28.154: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-20 13:44:28.154: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-20 13:44:28.154: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-20 13:44:28.154: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-20 13:44:28.154: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Are you sure it force closes because you set the adapter?

Comment: I didn't say it force closes because of the adapter. It force closes when I set the adapter.

Comment: If that's true, then it's also true that it force closes because you set it. Somehow.

Comment: @StirZoltán please check my answer. I belive it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.accountList);
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.id.accountList, TEXTS));


    }
```

Comment: I've modified the code as you said, but it's still not working. I'm attaching logcat

Comment: This helped but instead of R.id.accountList in the arrayadapter I used  R.layout.simple_list_item_1

Comment: @StirZoltán R.layout.simple_list_item_1 is a standard layout provided by android. If you want to customize it see my answer. At least I got it right :)

Answer (score 1):

The error is on line

```
lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.id.accountList, TEXTS));
```

The second argument expects a layout with only a TextView, something like this:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
```

Let's say you saved it in the file `list_row.xml` in your layout folder.

Then you do:

```
lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_row, TEXTS));
```

Comment: Why the downvote? If I am wrong what is the right answer then?

Comment: This was, in fact, the correct answer. Someone decided to go on a killing spree.

Comment: How do you adjust the list height or basic textview style?

Comment: @codenamezero you can change the properties of that TextView like background, textColor, etc. The list height depends on the items you have in there (or you can have a fixed height). You can also change each item size editing the layout_height property.

Answer (score 0):

try to set the xml to be:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
</ListView>
```

in addition, please paste your stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

It's throwing a `Resources$NotFoundException`, meaning there's probably something wrong with the `R.id.accountList`. It can't find it. I'm not sure but I think the adapter should point to R.layout.main since that's where the id is located.

```
lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.main, TEXTS));
```